# Reading Play Configuration in Sub Projects

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I have a Play 2.2 project that consists of multiple subprojects.

The build.sbt looks something like this:

```
lazy val common = project.in(file("sub-apps/common"))

lazy val api = project.in(file("sub-apps/api"))
    .dependsOn(common)
    .aggregate(common)

lazy val web = project.in(file("sub-apps/web"))
    .dependsOn(common)
    .aggregate(common)

...
```

However, I noticed that I cannot read a configuration value defined in api or web sub project's configuration.

`Play.current.configuration.getString("foobar")` returns None unless I define foobar in common's application conf.

Is there a way to read the configuration value defined in the sub project's conf?